# Next.js 9.5, global scss in _app throwing an error

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, next.js

When importing an Scss file from _app.js, an error is thrown and the page fails to render with the error : **Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null**

**Error :**

> was not caught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
> at Object.options.insert (index.scss?f260:14)
> at insertStyleElement (injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js?2dba:109)
> at addStyle (injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js?2dba:208)
> at modulesToDom (injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js?2dba:81)
> at module.exports (injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js?2dba:239)
> at eval (index.scss?f260:21)
> at Object../styles/index.scss (_app.js?ts=1596964640246:2465)
> at **webpack_require** (webpack.js?ts=1596964640246:873)
> at fn (webpack.js?ts=1596964640246:151)
> at Module.eval (_app.page.js:16)
> at eval (_app.page.js?f215:35)
> at Module../pages/_app.page.js (_app.js?ts=1596964640246:2346)
> at **webpack_require** (webpack.js?ts=1596964640246:873)
> at fn (webpack.js?ts=1596964640246:151)
> at eval (next-client-pages-loader.js?aaa7:5)
> at register (page-loader.js?d172:289)
> at PageLoader.registerPage (page-loader.js?d172:318)
> at Array.register [as push] (index.js?4a51:60)
> at eval (next-client-pages-loader.js?aaa7:2)
> at Object../node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-client-pages-loader.js?page=%2F_app&absolutePagePath=private-next-pages%2F_app.page.js!./
> (_app.js?ts=1596964640246:1282)
> at **webpack_require** (webpack.js?ts=1596964640246:873)
> at fn (webpack.js?ts=1596964640246:151)
> at Object.0 (_app.js?ts=1596964640246:2476)
> at **webpack_require** (webpack.js?ts=1596964640246:873)
> at checkDeferredModules (webpack.js?ts=1596964640246:46)

When click on the file where the error come from :

```
var content = require("!!../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!../../node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-loader/index.js??__nextjs_postcss!../../node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!../../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./styles.scss");

if (typeof content === 'string') {
  content = [[module.id, content, '']];
}

var options = {}

options.insert = function(element){// These elements should always exist. If they do not,
// this code should fail.
var anchorElement=document.querySelector('#__next_css__DO_NOT_USE__');var parentNode=anchorElement.parentNode;// Normally <head>
// Each style tag should be placed right before our
// anchor. By inserting before and not after, we do not
// need to track the last inserted element.
parentNode.insertBefore(element,anchorElement)// Remember: this is development only code.
//
// After styles are injected, we need to remove the
// <style> tags that set `body { display: none; }`.
//
// We use `requestAnimationFrame` as a way to defer
// this operation since there may be multiple style
// tags.
;(self.requestAnimationFrame||setTimeout)(function(){for(var x=document.querySelectorAll('[data-next-hide-fouc]'),i=x.length;i--;){x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);}});};
options.singleton = false;

var update = require("!../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js")(content, options);

if (content.locals) {
  module.exports = content.locals;
}

if (module.hot) {
  if (!content.locals) {
    module.hot.accept(
      "!!../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!../../node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-loader/index.js??__nextjs_postcss!../../node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!../../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./styles.scss",
      function () {
        var newContent = require("!!../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!../../node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-loader/index.js??__nextjs_postcss!../../node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!../../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./styles.scss");

        if (typeof newContent === 'string') {
          newContent = [[module.id, newContent, '']];
        }
        
        update(newContent);
      }
    )
  }

  module.hot.dispose(function() { 
    update();
  });
}
```

Comment: can you post `index.scss` line 260 please?

Comment: @RazRonen
var anchorElement=document.querySelector('#__next_css__DO_NOT_USE__');
var parentNode=anchorElement.parentNode;// Normally <head>

Comment: this is in .scss? vars in scss?

Comment: This isn' the syntax of defining vars in scss. This is: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables

Comment: this is what i have when i click on the error .....

Comment: I understand. The problem is `document.querySelector('#__next_css__DO_NOT_USE__')` doesn't find anything.

Comment: what selector are you trying to find?

Comment: this is generated by next.js ! but you're right the selector wasn't found !

Comment: I don't think you can use document.querySelector in next since its in server side.

Comment: Mind if I post an answer?

Comment: @RazRonen i added the full file where error comes from !

Comment: @RazRonen Yes please. can you post an answer. Got the same issue when trying to run production build.